# Having troubles connecting SQL database with Flask-SQLAlchemy 'sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError:'

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I was starting to learn Flask-SQLAlchemy and this was my first project, I was trying to make a blog Application. And I just can't connect this database!

I've tried several ways of connecting using several ways such as wrapping the connections in `try:` and `except:` code blocks. and alot of other things but none of theme seems to work.

```py
app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:\\\\E:\Blog\database.db'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

I've this code to connect the database right now, this throws the following error: `sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Could not parse rfc1738 URL from string 'E:\Blog\database.db'`

As far as I can understand the situation I think it is the error of the file path, but no file path seem to work! I've tried using: `sqlite:////mnt/e/Blog/database.db` From another stackOverflow instance but looks like it was for UNIX. Please help!

Comment: I think you have an extra backspace before `E:`. Please remove the extra backslash so that is now `'sqlite:\\\...'` instead of `'sqlite:\\\\...`.

Comment: Sorry to say, but this didn't work. I was following docs for the format of the URI. but i lost them, just doesn't seem to find it anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put forward slashes at the beginning not backward

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///C:\\absolute\\path\\to\\foo.db'
```